# Set tab length for a custom list made using a newcommand using tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, tocloft

I have some overlapping increment numbers of the item, with the title of the item of a custom list that I have defined.
[image]

The entry is inserted using a custom command as shown below but I don't understand how to set the tabulation so that the name of the item ( in the case of the figure below n.d.) is not overlapping with the increment number assigned to each item.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report} %
\usepackage{multicol} %
\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{6em}          
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{6em}

\newcommand{\listexamplename}{Lista dei beni librari.}
\newlistof{benelib}{mcf}{\listexamplename}

\title{test}



\newcommand{\benelib}[9]{\markboth{#1}{#1}\begin{large}\textbf{#1}\end{large}\ {(#2)}\ $\bullet$\ {#3}\ $\bullet$ \textbf{#4},\ #5,\ #6;\ #7,\ \begin{small}#8\end{small} Spagn.\ #9.
\refstepcounter{benelib}
\addcontentsline{mcf}{benelib}
{\protect\numberline{\thebenelib}#1} \par

}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listofbenelib
\newpage


\section*{Test}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\benelib{I}{1   }{[I1 3]}{thistitile}{asdf}{testtest}{400-600}{ }{49-50}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I read several questions but I could not find a way to apply the answers to my specific case. I was wondering how I have to modify the code to make it working properly.  My question is how to use `\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{6em}  \setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{6em}` for my custom list, and set the proper spacing of the incremental numbering and the item name?

Comment: Please provide an MWE that actually produces the overlapping numbers. Where does the "n.d" come from?

Comment: @PeterWilson Hi, you can repeat \benelib{I}{1   }{[I1 3]}{thistitile}{asdf}{testtest}{400-600}{ }{49-50} 1000 times an the numbers will be overlapping. I don't want to make a MWE so long.  "n.a" is just a field. The question is regarding setting the width of the text reserved for the number. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tested by inserting `\setcounter{benelib}{10000}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
\setlength\cftbenelibnumwidth{6em}
```

In a more general vein, `\numberline` can be made to never overlap numbers and titles, no matter what width is specified. (`\@tempdima` is the width for the number, at the time `\numberline` does its work.)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{%
\begingroup
 \sbox\@tempboxa{#1 }%
 \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa<\@tempdima
  \wd\@tempboxa=\@tempdima
 \fi
 \usebox\@tempboxa
\endgroup
}
\makeatother
```